# SkyDrive PRO Form based authentication

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

I am new to Sharepoint and this is my second time i am going to do something on Sharepoint. I was assigned a task to research about SkyDrive Pro to find out the possibility of having form based authentication in SkyDrive Pro.

I searched alot but there is nothing available for the authentication of SkyDrive pro on the internet. I have the following questions

1- Is this possible to have Form Based Authentication for SkyDrive Pro ? I am looking for options (in SkyDrive Pro Desktop application) like Settings > Change Authentication Method > Select Method > Username/Password.

2- Any helpful links to understand the authentication machanism of SkyDrive Pro.

Thank you in advance.